Patch 30392 - partially works - PayPal goes thru but attendee is not added to the event
I am starting a new thread as this might also occur if someone installs the patch below and also as this patch is going into the next release.
This is a continuation of Upgrade from 5.65.1 to 5.74.0 - Error "Expected to find one Participant record, but there were zero." when registering for an event
Tha patch that was suggested https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30392.patch,
seems to partially work as the PayPal payment goes thru and we do receive the funds.
However we have noticed that the new registered participant is not being added to the event. When we look at the new participant record -in the Event tab -it shows that the participant has the status as "Pending (incomplete transaction)".
Any help what we do here will be greatly appreciated. Thx.

Are you getting ipn call from Paypal?

@Pradeep, yes we get a notification from  PayPal but not from Civi as we collect information from the participant through a profile. The profile form collects information about the participant. This was working before the upgrade and patch installation.

@Pradeep - would update 5.74.1,  5.74.2,  5.74.3,  5.74.4,  help with my issue? As I am running 5.74.0

I think it need debugging, do you want to?

@Pradeep - I have no experience in the depths of Civi but happy for someone to guide me to get a  fix for this problem

Do you want to get in touch on skype at pradp_nayak

@Pradeep - Sure will do I will send some details via Skype .
